# windows batch SET inside IF not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

when I'm running this script (from a .bat file):

```
set var1=true
if "%var1%"=="true" (
  set var2=myvalue
  echo %var2%
)
```

I always get:

```
ECHO is on.
```

Meaning the `var2` variable was not really set.
Can anyone please help me understand why?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

var2 is set, but the expansion in the line `echo %var2%` occurs before the block is executed.
At this time `var2` is empty.

Therefore the delayedExpansion syntax exists, it uses `!` instead of `%` and it is evaluated at execution time, not parse time.

Please note that in order to use `!`, the additional statement `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` is needed.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var1=true
if "%var1%"=="true" (
  set var2=myvalue
  echo !var2!
)
```

Comment: Same rule to `&` and `&&`operators. This code `set x=some & set y=%x%thing  & echo results %y%` outputs `%x%thing`.

Comment: Sauce: "_With loop commands like FOR, compound or **bracketed** expressions, Delayed Expansion will allow you to always read the current value of the variable. [[1](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)]_" and, just to show parens _are_ brackets, "_Use parentheses-**brackets**... A GOTO command inside a **bracketed** code block will break the **parentheses** context... [[2](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html)]_" (emph mine). It's really kinda hard imo to google up definitive stuff on `if` & `batch`, though I've googled enough to learn if jeb (no `!`) says it, it's going to be right.

Answer (score 22):

I am a bit late to the party but another way to deal with this condition is to continue process outside `if`, like this

```
set var1=true
if "%var1%"=="true" (
    set var2=myvalue
)
echo %var2%
```

Or/and use `goto` syntax

```
set var1=true
if "%var1%"=="true" (
    set var2=myvalue
    goto line10
) else (
    goto line20
)
. . . . .
:line10
echo %var2%
. . . . . 
:line20
```

This way expansion occurs "in time" and you don't need `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`. Bottom line, if you rethink design of your script you can do it like that

Comment: I am unable to access a variable I created inside an if statement. Your first example with var2 does not work.

Comment: @AntonioCS interesting... this is exact script that I just tested `echo off
set var1=true
if "%var1%"=="true" (
    set var2=myvalue
)
echo %var2%
pause`.. and it is working. *"if you will create a variable in the batch file that it can be accessed anywhere in the program."*.  https://aticleworld.com/batch-file-variables-and-scope/