# Variable not printing (ECHO) inside IF statement of batch file

Tags: batch-file

For some reason I can't get %NetVerClientOrFull% to print inside of the IF statement. This is really weird because it sometimes does and sometimes doesn't even when I don't change anything. I have tested on multiple machines with the same results. If I use %NetVer% inside the IF statement is always prints. Any ideas what is going on?

ECHO Client or Full? %NetVerClientOrFull%     (should display Client or Full and sometimes does)

```
@echo off
  set frameworkDirectory=Reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP"
  FOR /F "TOKENS=6 DELIMS=\." %%A IN ('%frameworkDirectory%') DO set NetVer=%%A
  ECHO The most current version of the .NET Framework installed is: %NetVer% 

  if "%NetVer%"=="v4" (
  set clientOrFullDirectory=Reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4"
  FOR /F "TOKENS=7 DELIMS=\." %%A IN ('%clientOrFullDirectory%') DO set NetVerClientOrFull=%%A
  ECHO Client or Full? %NetVerClientOrFull%

  )

pause
```

To add onto this it seems like it works on my third run, makes no sense:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Nick>C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\FrameworkVersionChecker.bat
The most current version of the .NET Framework installed is: v4
Client or Full?
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\Users\Nick>C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\FrameworkVersionChecker.bat
The most current version of the .NET Framework installed is: v4
Client or Full?
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\Users\Nick>C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\FrameworkVersionChecker.bat
The most current version of the .NET Framework installed is: v4
Client or Full? Full
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because parser expands variables when it **reads** a block, not when it's statements are executed. Your statements inside `if ()` block see variables as they were set **before entry** to this block. This problem, and how to overcome it (by use of delayed expansion)  is well explained in `set` help. Just execute `help set` from command line - there is even similar example included. It's also explained here: [windows batch SET inside IF not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102422/windows-batch-set-inside-if-not-working)

Why it prints on third (and subsequent) run? You do not use `setlocal` - thus when you execute your batch next time it will see variables as set in previous run. Remove or remark `@echo off`, and execute your batch from freshly started console. You will see how variables get expanded and why it works only 3rd time onwards.