# Rotating a log based on certain size into a date/time-stamped copy

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

It so happens that there is a BAT file running a certain command line tool on a Windows server 2008 and redirects output to an ever-growing log that I want to rotate every time it outgrows certain size. It would be time and effort consuming to change that BAT file into a CMD, needless to say PowerShell PS1. So I am constrained to editing that BAT file.

Everything below is being tested on Windows 7 and 2008.

Tried the following:

```vb
for %%I in (Log.txt) do @echo %%~zI >> size.tmp
set /p logSIZE=<size.tmp
del size.tmp
if %logSIZE% GTR 100 (
  echo OK
)
```

the test `Log.txt` was 157 bytes at that time and so it echoed `OK`. Then I did a negative test by increasing 100 to 200 and it did not echo `OK`. So far so good.

Next I tried to concatenate date and time stamps into the a file name:

```vb
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set dateStamp=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set timeStamp=%%a%%b)
echo Log_%dateStamp%_%timeStamp%.txt
```

and that worked like a charm too. Next step is to combine both scripts into one:

```vb
for %%I in (Log.txt) do @echo %%~zI >> size.tmp
set /p logSIZE=<size.tmp
del size.tmp
if %logSIZE% GTR 100 (
  For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set dateStamp=%%c-%%a-%%b)
  For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set timeStamp=%%a%%b)
echo %dateStamp%
echo %timeStamp%
  rem move Log.txt "Log%dateStamp%_%timeStamp%.txt"
)
```

but that no longer worked, as despite the script visibly entering the `if` block and executing the `set` commands with the current date/time values, the environment variables remain blank. The `echo` commands do not output anything and the new file name consists of only `Log__.txt`.

I tried to debug this by adding the following lines at the beginning of the file:

```vb
set dateStamp=A
set timeStamp=B
echo %dateStamp%
echo %timeStamp%

for %%I in (Log.txt) do @echo %%~zI >> size.tmp
set /p logSIZE=<size.tmp
del size.tmp
if %logSIZE% GTR 100 (
  For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set dateStamp=%%c-%%a-%%b)
  For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set timeStamp=%%a%%b)
echo %dateStamp%
echo %timeStamp%
  rem move Log.txt "Log%dateStamp%_%timeStamp%.txt"
)
```

that worked correctly, assigning A and B to the variables, but then those values were not re-assigned the date and time stamps within the `if` block.

I know how to work around that by keeping the environment variable assignment outside the `if` block:

```vb
for %%I in (Log.txt) do @echo %%~zI >> size.tmp
set /p logSIZE=<size.tmp
del size.tmp

For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set dateStamp=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set timeStamp=%%a%%b)

if %logSIZE% GTR 100 (
    echo Log_%dateStamp%_%timeStamp%.txt
)
```

but still want to get to the bottom of it in case in the future I would have to assign variables inside an `if` block.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Search for enabledelayedexpansion. Your variables get replaced with their value at the beginning of the block.

Comment: Great answer, but you should not have changed the question title as doing that in a BAT file is significant to the question. I don't care, but the future readers may not realize it addresses their issue too.

Comment: That's what tags are for; you tagged your question with [tag:batch-file] so it's perfectly clear...

Answer (score 1):

*Posting this, so this question at least had a answer that others can quickly catch, as I did not see the actual answer in the comments. @ths should repost to receive the credit.*

As @ths pointed out in the question's comment, the script needs `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning to correct the behavior.

You can read more about it from this previous question on the same subject.
[windows batch SET inside IF not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102422/windows-batch-set-inside-if-not-working)