# I am having issues with if-statements in Batch File

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I am working on a script in batch for deleting files from all directories on my computer. I have the basics laid out, but I've run into an issue. I will put my code below.

But what is happening is that when I run the code I can't make it past the first if-statement, I inserted pauses after each line so I could find out where the problem is and that's how I know this.

What happens when I run the code is that it runs properly, it opens a terminal window, and it prompts the user for input. Immediately after I give the input though, something with the if-statement it close the window.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

### The Code

---

```
set /p choice=Please enter 1 to continue or 0 to return to menu: 
if %choice%==1 (
    pause
    Set /P inp=Please enter a file name: 
    pause
    for /f %%F in (C:\Program Files)(
        if "%%F" == "%inp%" (
        goto:remo
    )
)
```

(I haven't finished the code entirely yet, I'm just making sure the parts that I have made run properly.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [windows batch SET inside IF not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102422/windows-batch-set-inside-if-not-working)

Comment: @Squashman that doesn't quite answer my question, but I appreciate the help, also if my question needs rephrasing to make it easier to understand just tell me. :)

Comment: @T3RR0R That doesn't quite answer my question either, but i appreciate the help none the less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a for loop to find a single file? Also, for these types of menus, rather use the `choice` command and use the `errorlevel` Here we test if the file exists in `"C:\Program Files\"` instead of `for` looping through it:

```
@echo off
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo Program Delete
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
choice /c 12 /m "1. Continue 2. Goto menu
goto :opt%errorlevel%

:opt1
:: Delete option is option 1 or %errorlevel% of 1
Set /P inp=Please enter a file name: 
if exist "C:\Program Files\%inp%" call :remo

:opt2
::Menu goes under option 2 or %errorlevel% of 2
```