# Batch Script - Using Variable with SCP command

Tags: windows, batch-file, scp

I have a simple batch script which transfers a file `filename` to a remote location `destination` using SCP.

Using `scp filename destination` works perfectly fine, however adding variable `var` doesn't work.

Code snippet:

```
set /p "var=filename"
echo %var%
echo scp "%var%" destination
scp "%var%" destination
```

Results:

```
filename
scp "" destination
: not a regular file
```

The variable is not used or recognized by the second `echo` and `scp`.

Is there something I'm missing from using the variable properly in echo and scp?

Note: Code snippet is in an if statement

Solution:
Need to use `delayexpansion`, and use `!var!` instead of`%var%`

See here: [windows batch SET inside IF not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102422/windows-batch-set-inside-if-not-working)

Comment: `Set /P` prompts for input. When `filename` appears on your screen, you're supposed to type it, and press the `[ENTER]` key. From what you've posted, it is clear that you are just pressing the `[ENTER]` key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the snippet you posted.
But these lines will fail in the way you describe if these lines are within a parenthesized codeblock.
If this is the case then you must change the code to use delayed expansion.
See `setlocal/?` and `set/?` for details and documentation.

Comment: Yes the code is within an if statement, this was helpful with looking into set, setlocal and enabledelayedexpansion